# Time zone conversion between UTC and local time + possibly daylight saving

Tags: sql, datetime, hana

I'm struggling to deal with time zone and daylight saving when querying SAP HANA. The datetime stamp is in the form of NVARCHAR, eg `20210304132500` YYYYMMDDHHMISS in UTC, which means local time is `14:25:00(GMT +01:00)` but my query returns `13:25:00 (UTC)`. How do I edit my results to match local time? Sample query below if that helps.

```
SELECT DATE_TIME,LOCATION,PART_NUMB
FROM "PUBLIC"."internal.sap.datamodel::ACTIVITY" 
WHERE SUBSTRING(DATE_TIME,9,2) IN ('08','11')`
```

The desired result is local date_time in any format.

Comment: I edited your question mainly concerning the term "daylight saving" which seems to be used instead of term "time zone". Of course daylight saving is part of local time concept but seems minor related to the question. Could you please review it if you don't agree? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HANA comes with timezone conversion functions ([`UTCTOLOCAL`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/20f52f4475191014a1089242486060c1.html)) that can perform the necessary calculations.

These functions require that the data/time input is in either SQL date/time format or that it can be converted to that. They also require that the timezone data has been set up and maintained in the HANA DB. This is the actual information about which timezone has which offsets and daylight saving begin and end times.

For your example, it may make sense to expose the `DATE_TIME` as a type converted field `DATE_TIME_UTC` that is already in sql-date time:

```
to_seconddate (DATE_TIME, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS') as DATE_TIME_UTC
```

With this conversion done, you can convert the timezone like this:

```
UTCTOLOCAL (DATE_TIME_UTC, 'Berlin', 'platform') as LOCAL_DATE_TIME
```

Note, that the target time zone name *may* be something like "GMT+1" but this is really just a name and **not** a calculation instruction. If "GMT+1" is not found in the list of timezone conversions, HANA won't just add an hour - it won't perform the calculation.

With this data type **and** timezone conversion done, you could have a WHERE clause like this:

```
 WHERE 
    HOUR(LOCAL_DATE_TIME) IN (8, 11)
```

This order of transformations (data type -> time zone -> hour component) is *of course* rather expensive. It may be worthwhile to check whether the resulting query performance is satisfactory on realistic data volume.

Also important to note is that time zone conversion only works on complete date-time information, not just the time. That is to say, if the date is unknown, it cannot be determined which offset rule between two time zone applies. So, simply separating the hours and date components won't help in this case.

Finally, I've written quite a bit about handling date, time, and time zones in HANA, you may want to have a look at that:

- [The time is now, isn’t it?](https://www.lbreddemann.org/the-time-is-now-isnt-it/)
- [Trouble with time?](https://www.lbreddemann.org/trouble-with-time/)
- [You got the time?](https://www.lbreddemann.org/you-got-the-time/)